# How to create a edit profile page for users with PHP?

Tags: php, html

I've created a page but I can´t put the Save button working and regardless of the user I enter with, it appears the same user information for them all.
I think it's a loop problem but I'm not sure what it is.

```
 <?php
    require_once('LoginConfig.php');

    session_start();  
    if(isset($_SESSION["email"])){
        $user_check = $_SESSION["email"];

        $result = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :usercheck");
        $result->execute(array(":usercheck"=>$user_check));    
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else  
    {  
         header("location:UsersLogin.php");  
    } 
    
 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="PT-pt">
<head>
    <title> Editar Perfil - JamJam </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700, 600,500,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style-menu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style-articlelist2.css">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/8a368d3752.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<style>
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo">
        <i style='font-size:24px' class='fas'>&#xf58f;</i>
         <span style='font-size:24px'>JamJam</span>
        </div>
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="nav-trigger"><span></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="side-nav">
        <div class="logo">
        <i style='font-size:24px; color:rgb(0,255,0)' class='fas'>&#xf58f;</i>
            <span style='font-size:24px'>JamJam</span>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="UsersMenu.php">
                        <span><i style='color:rgb(0,255,0)' class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                        <span>Página Inicial</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="UsersProfile.php">
                        <span><i style='color:rgb(0,255,0)' class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        <span>Perfil</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="UsersArticleList.php">
                        <span><i style='color:rgb(0,255,0)' style='font-size:16px' class='fas'>&#xf001</i></span>
                        <span>Músicas</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Logout.php">
                        <span><i style='color:rgb(0,255,0)' class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></span>
                        <span>Logout</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
            <div class="title">
                Editar Perfil
            </div>
            <div class="main">
                <div class="widget" style="lex-basis: 98%; height: 750px;"> 
              <?php

                    if(isset($_SESSION["email"])){
                        $result = $connect->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_bio, user_local, user_image FROM users");
                        $result->bindParam(':userid', $id);
                        $result->execute();
                        $row = $result->fetch()
                  
                                            
                ?>

                    <form style="text-align: left; margin: 15px; " action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"> 
                    
                    <input $id="user_id" name="user_id" type="hidden" value= "<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>">

                    <div >
                        <label for="username">Nome:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $row['user_name']; ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label for="bio">Bio:</label>
                        <br>
                        <textarea type="text" class="textarea" name="bio" rows ="4"><?php echo $row['user_bio']; ?></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label for="local">Sítio onde vive:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="local" value="<?php echo $row['user_local']; ?>">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                    <label for="image">Foto de perfil atual:</label><br>
                    <img src="<?php echo 'images/' . $row['user_image']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                       <br> <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <lable for="image">Selecionar nova foto de perfil:</lable><br>
                        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                        </form>
                    </div>

                  
                    <div style="text-align: left; margin: 10px;" class="box">
                     <button style="float: left;" class="saveButton" type="submit">Guardar</button>
                     <a style="float: right;" class="cancelButton" href="UsersProfile.php">Cancelar</a>
                    </div>
                    
                    </form>
                    
                    <?php
                        }
                      
                    ?> 
                
                </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On this line `$result->bindParam(':userid', $id);` you are referring to the variable `$id` but no where in your code are you actually setting that value.

Comment: Did you want to use `WHERE userid = :id`?

Comment: I've tryed to use the WHERE but it gives me an error